# Ionic 2 after used DomSanitizer change style didn't work

Tags: ionic2

I tried to change style with DOM in my project, but in my browser didn't change anything. when i tried to create console the DOM structure was change. Any idea?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div (press)="showBookmarkOption($event)">
  <div *ngFor="let item of isicontent; let i = index" class="content-wrap datanum-{{i}}" #contentwrapper>
    <h3 [innerHTML]="this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item.title)"></h3>
    <div [innerHTML]="this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item.content)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
showBookmarkOption(e){

    this.BookmarkTargetDatanum  = e.target.closest('.content-wrap').classList[1].replace('datanum-','');

    let BookmarkTarget:any                  = e.target.closest('div').id;
    if(BookmarkTarget == ''){
        return false;
    }
    let BookmarkMarkdown:any                = document.getElementById(BookmarkTarget);
    let BookmarkMarkdownOffsetTop:any       = BookmarkMarkdown.offsetTop;
    let BookmarkMarkdownOffsetHeight:any    = BookmarkMarkdown.offsetHeight;

    this.bookmarkContent                            = e;
    this.bookmarkContent.target.style.background    = "yellow";

    console.log(e.target);

    actionSheet.present();
}
```

and the result is

[image: result]

Comment: what is item.title and item.content?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj you can see here http://plnkr.co/edit/CYFkXwJEtOv5n8kEf6bT and the DOM working. But in my project was not

Comment: showBookmarkOption is missing in plunkr

Comment: @PrithiviRaj how to add tshowBookmarkOption in plunkr?

Comment: did you able to trigger press event from your application?

Comment: @PrithiviRaj sure, console in the picture is from press event console.log(e.target);